# Separate DateTime to Date and Time with time zone `Z` at the end, in Joda-Time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object and need to have date and time separately, with time zone label at the end:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
System.out.println(dateTime.toString("YYYY-MM-ddZ"));
System.out.println(dateTime.toString("HH:mm:ssZ"));
```

In this case the output will be:

```
2014-02-27+0000
15:10:36+0000
```

Almost exactly what I need, but it is possible to have it like this?

```
2014-02-27Z
15:10:36Z
```

Comment: is this using jodatime? You should state that in your question if so. Any reason not to use std java api?

Comment: @rainkinz: There are *lots* of reasons to use Joda Time rather than the standard (pre-8) Java API. But yes, the question really should state that this is about Joda Time.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why? You cannot tell the exact time from a date alone even with timezone information, and the same for date vs time...

Comment: that's just an API requirement, how we should populate a JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
            .appendTimeZoneOffset("Z", false, 2, 2)
            .toFormatter();
System.out.println(formatter.print(dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone
            .forID("Zulu"))));
```

Basically, if the [time zone offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) is zero, you print `Z`. Since `Zulu` or `UTC` has an offset of 0, that's what will be printed.

Comment: Correct answer, but code could be briefer. (a) `DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date();` yields a formatter for yyyy-MM-dd. You generally should not need to use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` unless you need a really screwy format. (b) Instead of `DateTimeZone.forID("Zulu")` use `DateTimeZone.UTC` constant.

Comment: @basil ISO is where I got the idea for this, but that pattern doesn't look like it has the timezone offset.

Comment: Ah, I see now that the Question wants a 'Z' at end. I missed that on first reading. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use Military codes (i.e. Z for GMT see: http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/military/z.html) you could so something like this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import java.util.Date;

public class CalendarExample {

  static final String MILITARY_OFFSETS = "YXWVUTSRQPONZABCDEFGHIKLM";
  static final int MILLIS_IN_HOUR = 1000*60*60;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(formatDate(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd", "GMT")); // 2014-02-27Z
    System.out.println(formatDate(new Date(), "HH:mm:ss", "GMT"));
    System.out.println(formatDate(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd", "EST"));
    System.out.println(formatDate(new Date(), "HH:mm:ss", "EST"));
  }

  static String formatDate(Date date, String dateTimeFormat, String timezoneCode) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneCode);
    calendar.setTimeZone(tz);
    int offset = calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)/MILLIS_IN_HOUR;

    // System.out.println(timezoneCode + " Offset is " + offset + " hours");
    String timeZoneCode = MILITARY_OFFSETS.substring(offset + 12, offset + 13);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFmt = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat + "'" + timeZoneCode + "'");

    return dateFmt.format(date);
  }

}
```

output:

```
2014-02-27Z
11:57:44Z
2014-02-27R
11:57:44R
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
System.out.println(dateTime.toString("YYYY-MM-dd z");
System.out.println(dateTime.toString("HH:mm:ss z");
```

Use "z" instead of "Z".

Comment: No, this won't work. `Z` is a timezone alias for GMT. It won't be valid if your timezone is anything else.

Comment: the output will be `2014-02-27 GMT` instead of `2014-02-27Z`